# Special count in a column of a pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
| parameter |
|-----------|
| A         |
| B         |
| C         |
| A         |
| D         |
| C         |
| A         |
| E         |
```

I like to count the occurance of parameter **above** the current row in a second column. So the desired output is like this:

| parameter | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 0 |
| C | 0 |
| A | 1 |
| D | 0 |
| C | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| E | 0 |

Is this possible without looping each row?
The table may also be resorted if necessary.
I need it lateron as an index for pivoting a table.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C", "A", "E"], columns=["parameter"])

df["cum_count"] = df.groupby("parameter").cumcount()
```

This does the trick. Group by the column you are trying to get a cumulative count of and use the .cumcount() function. This numbers each item in each group from 0 to the length of that group - 1.

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html